# $xe^x$ even or odd?

Tags: functions, logarithms, even-and-odd-functions

I have this simple function:

$$xe^x$$

Is it an even or odd function? How can I prove it?

For even functions, we have:

$$f(x)=f(-x)$$

For odd functions, we have:

$$-f(x)=f(-x)$$

I have only got the hint that it is an even function but my logic says odd.

Comment: Its neither even nor odd function!

Comment: It is neither...

Comment: So that is why I get stuck. Can you explain more?

Comment: not all functions are either even or odd. that is, $¬even\not \Rightarrow odd$ or viceversa

Comment: **Tip:** You can use mathjax in the title as well.

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to decide if a function is "even or odd" without knowing what those words **mean**.  A function is "even" if and only if f(-x)= f(x) for all x.  In this case, is $(-x)e^{-x}= xe^x$ for all x?  No, it is not because if x= 1, that would be $-\frac{1}{e}= e$ which is not true.   A function is "odd" if and only if f(-x)= -f(x).  In this case, is $(-x)e^{-x}= -xe^x$ for all x?  No, because if x= 1, that would be $-e= -\frac{1}{e}$ which is not true.

Comment: For information. The even component of $f(x)$ is $\frac {f(x)+f(-x)}2$ and the odd component is $\frac {f(x)-f(-x)}2$, this splits any function into the sum of an even function and an odd function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that

$$f(x)=xe^x\neq f(-x)=-xe^{-x}$$

$$f(x)=xe^x\neq -f(-x)=xe^{-x}$$

Indeed

$$xe^x=-xe^{-x}\iff x(e^x+e^{-x})=0 \iff x=0 \quad \lor \quad e^x+e^{-x}=0 $$

$$xe^x=xe^{-x}\iff x(e^x-e^{-x})=0 \iff x=0 \quad \lor \quad e^x-e^{-x}=0 $$

since the equalities hold only for $x=0$, $f(x)$ is **neither odd or even**.

On the other hand,

$$g(x)=xe^{|x|}$$

is odd.

Comment: And to prove $xe^x\neq -xe^{-x}$, just plug in any nonzero value of $x$, for example $x=1$.

Answer (score 4):

$$f(1)=e$$
$$f(-1)=\frac{-1}{e}$$
$$f(1) \neq f(-1)$$
$$f(1) \neq -f(-1)$$

Comment: I think it's the best answer here. +1

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$f (x) = xe^x \text { and } f (-x) = -xe^{-x} $$

Note that $e^x $ isn't related to $e^{-x} $ other than the fact that they are multiplicative inverses of each other and are equal only at $x =0$. Can we relate the two functions? **No.** $$f (x) \neq f (-x) \text { and } f (x) \neq -f (-x) $$

Hence, $f (x) $ is **neither even nor odd**.

Comment: You might want to specify that $\mathrm{e}^{-x}$ is the *multiplicative* inverse of $\mathrm{e}^x$.  As functions, the inverse of $\mathrm{e}^{x}$ is $\log(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $xe^x \to+\infty$ as $x\to+\infty$ and $xe^x\to0$ as $x\to-\infty.$ That implies this function is neither even nor odd.

(The second limit can be shown by L'Hopital's rule applied to $\dfrac x {e^{-x}}.$ It can also be shown by more common-sense methods.)